# What's the easiest way to zip/rar/arj a directory with a timestamp for a name?

Tags: windows-xp, archiving

What would be the easiest way of zipping/raring/arjing a directory with a timestamp for a name?

Comment: And, you know, it would make a **lot of sense** to use a YYYYMMDD date format so the backups are listed in chronological order (and it's easy to see if the one you want is there).

Comment: @pavium - of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the console you can do

```
rar a -r "backup-%DATE%.rar" "C:\Path\To\Directory"
```

If you also want the the time in the archive name, things get more complicated since `%TIME%` usually contains characters illegal for a file name (like `:`). To remove the colons form `%TIME%`, you could use some wired `for`-loop syntax:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:" %i IN ("%TIME%") DO (
      rar a -r "backup-%DATE%-%i.%j.%k.rar" "C:\Path\To\Directory"
   )
```

(See `for /?` for details on what this does.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a quick Explorer-based pointy-clicky solution, here's the way I'd use:

1. First, for quick zipping, use WinZip's **Add To Zip** Explorer context menu option on the folder.
2. Then, use [Synesis Software's Shell Extensions](http://shellext.synesis.com.au/#medatemv) **Date Renamer** context menu option on the resulting zip archive:

[image: Date Renamer]

I would imagine there are other solutions that are equally short but use different shell extensions.

Comment: Of course, I'm curious if there's a **single-step** pointy-clicky solution that doesn't involve coding it oneself ;-)